# VB Change Hover Color on all Buttons

Tags: vb.net

I currently have this code to change the Fore, or back color on all of my buttons:

```
Private Sub SetAllLabelsForeColor(ByVal parent As Control)

    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is Button And c.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            c.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White 'I AM STUCK HERE
        Else
            If c.HasChildren Then
                SetAllLabelsForeColor(c)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If I am wondering if there is chance to change the "On Hover" color on all these buttons. I can normally change the hover color through:

```
Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White
```

But it seems as if the Control doesn't recognize FlatAppearance. I have tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
c.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White
```

Is there an alternative way, or a similar way for me to change the hover color on all my buttons?

Comment: you can use `css:` `.button:hover {   background-color: red; color: white; }`

Comment: I have no knowledge except for the basic use of CSS in HTML. Do I create a stylesheet and reference it to my form?

Comment: you can create a stylesheet or put the css code on your html view, then you just need to atribute a class to `button` read: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp

Comment: Oh, well, I think you read my title incorrectly. I am working in Visual Studio with Visual Basic. I have a form with a couple of button and want to change the hover color of them. I think you believe that I am using a HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button images, transparency, MouseOver colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568506/button-images-transparency-mouseover-colors)

Comment: @MagicSenseixd : This is WinForms, not ASP.NET. An ASP.NET button doesn't have the `FlatAppearance` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast your control to a button:

```
Dim b = DirectCast(c, Button)
b.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White 'I AM STUCK HERE
```

This gives you access to what you need.

Comment: [**`DirectCast`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) is a better choice in this case **as we are certain** that `c` is a button. `CType` should (almost) only be used when converting to a _**different**_ type.

Comment: @Visual Thanks, I made the change.